# Why is ocaml giving applied to too many arguments error?

Tags: ocaml

I have the following code:

```
type value =    (* an integer or an error message *)                                                                                    
  | Value of int                                                                                                                        
  | Error of string;;  

let rec compare_v (lo: value) (ro: value) : value =                                                                                         
  match lo with                                                                                                                         
  | Value(l) ->                                                                                                                         
     match ro with                                                                                                                      
     | Value (r) -> if l == r then Value(1) else Value(-1)
```

And running `compare_v Value(9) Value(10);;` gives:

```
Line 1, characters 0-9:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
1 | compare_v Value(9) Value(10);;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    ^^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Error: This function has type value -> value -> value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
       It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'.
```

Why is that the case?

Answer (score 2):

The parse of this subexpression:

```
compare_v Value(9)
```

Is something like this:

```
(compare_v Value) (9)
```

In OCaml function application is denoted just by juxtaposition (putting two expressions side by side), and it is left associative. In this expression you have three expressions side by side:

```
compare_v  Value   (9)
```

The left associativity is giving the result you're seeing.

What you should write is:

```
compare_v (Value 9)
```

In OCaml you need to use parentheses differently than in mainstream (Algolic) languages. Parentheses don't have anything in particular to do with calling a function, they are purely for grouping of subexpressions.